# unexpected behavior in core.logic conjo goal

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I have hard time understanding the following behavior of the `conjo` goal in core.logic.

First, everything seems fine.

```
(l/run* [q]
  (l/conjo q 2 3 [1 2 3] )) => ([1])
```

The goal succeeds when `q = [1]`, since `(conj [1] 2 3) == [1 2 3]`

When on the otherhand I ask for 2 `lvars` then I get the following result that I don't understand. I was expecting `a = [1]` and `b = 2`.

```
(l/run* [a b]
  (l/conjo a b 3 [1 2 3] )) => (([_0 _1] :- (clojure.core.logic/conjo <lvar:a__25296> _1 3 [1 2 3])))
```

What does the syntax `:- (clojure.core.logic/conjo <lvar:a__25296>` mean?
Why do I get unbound `lvars` for a and b? there is only one possibility for the goal to suceed.

Maybe I need to hint it some more.

```
(l/run* [a b]
  (l/== b 2)
  (l/conjo a b 2 [1 2 3])) => ()
```

That's really strange now. I set `b` to be explicitly be `2` and then no solution for a exists.

Any clue what I miss here?

*Edit*
There's a typo in the example above. The last one should really be:

```
(l/run* [a b]
  (l/== b 2)
  (l/conjo a b 3 [1 2 3])) => ()
```

Comment: The `()` result for your last query is clearly correct: There's no vector you can conj 2 onto and end with `[1 2 3]`. To be specific, the error is in `(conjo a b 2 ...)`, where previously you have had 3 instead; `(== b 2)` is fine.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the third example. Indeed I wanted to evaluate `(run* [a b] (== b 2) (conjo a b 3 [1 2 3]))` and you also get an empty result. So still both are not clear